# Flutter - Firebase SDK

Tags: firebase, flutter, mobile, sdk

I am developing an application on Flutter.

I'm using Firebase's Realtime Database and I'm not using the SDK, I'm using it for REST.

If I choose to use the Firebase SDK. Will I have to configure it on both Android and IOS?

Or I configuring only on one of the platforms is for everyone.

I'm programming on Windows, could I configure it for the Firebase SDK for IOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter compiles down to native apps for each platform you want to support. So if you want to target both Android and iOS, you'll need to configure an app in the Firebase project in the Firebase console for each of those, and add the resulting configuration file to the native runner in the Flutter project on your dev machine.

Developing for iOS on Windows is not common/straightforward, but it is possible as far as I know. I recommend doing a separate search for that, as you mostly need a way to run Xcode - it is not specific to Firebase nor to Flutter.